# Running a for loop in Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0, azure-powershell

I am new o scripting in powershell and am from a Python background. I want to know if I'm doing this right.
I created this array and want to extract each item one by one

$M365_E3_Grps = ("O365-CHN-DomainUser,O365-Vendor-Exchange-User")
ForEach ($Indiv_Grp in $M365_E3_Grps) {

ForEach ($Indiv_Grp in $M365_E3_Grps) {

```
`$ADGroup = $Indiv_Grp$ADGroup = $Indiv_Grp`
```

I want to know if we can extract vals with a for loop like this and assign it to a variable like this.

Comment: Maybe the documentation for ```foreach``` will help you… https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 0):

#### Construct of your array

Your array is not quite correct and will be populated as a string. To create a string array you will need to quote each item in comma separated list. The parentheses are also not required.

```
$M365_E3_Grps = "O365-CHN-DomainUser","O365-Vendor-Exchange-User"
```

Your `foreach` keyword syntax is however correct, even if the formatting in your question was slightly off.

```
foreach ($Indiv_Grp in $M365_E3_Grps) {
    # Assigning $Indiv_Grp to $ADGroup here is kind of redundant since
    # the value is already assinged to $Indiv_Grp
    $Indiv_Grp
}
```